# regex for currency (euro)

Tags: php, regex, validation

i am trying this code for make a validation for a value. (regex from this [site](http://regexlib.com/Default.aspx))

UPDATE:

Now i have

```
$value1=250;    

$value2=10000;

        if (!preg_match("/^(([^0]{1})([0-9])*|(0{1}))(\,\d{2}){0,1}€?$/", $form['salary']) || (!$form['salary'])>$value1."€" && (!$form['salary'])<$value2."€" ){
        echo ("invalido");
        return false;
    }
    else
    echo ("valido");
    return true;
```

the code works well, but 20€ is accepted, so the problem now is not the regex, but compare values like 200€ or 1000€.

**this probably is wrong**

```
(!$form['salary'])>$value1."€"
```

example some Input values:

```
    200€
    200
    200.5
    200.50€

limits - 250€ to 10000€
```

thanks

Comment: remember most `€` signs are `&euro;` for internationalization

Comment: Do you want to support a € prefix, suffix or both?

Comment: @Fel That complicates things immensely as I'd imagine you'd want to match a prefix or suffix but *not* both

Comment: at the moment i have this: /^(([^0]{1})([0-9])*|(0{1}))(\,\d{2}){0,1}€?$/    -- only woks with suffix, but ok, the main problem now is the interval of values

Comment: Does this problem have to be solved with (a) a regular expression and (b) just one regular expression?

Comment: is indifferent. the important thing is to work. As i said, at the moment the only problem is the interval of values. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code below solved my problem:

```
if (!preg_match("/^(([^0]{1})([0-9])*|(0{1}))(\,\d{2}){0,1}€?$/", $form['salary'])) {
    echo "invalid";
    return false;
} else {
    $value1 = 400;
    $value2 = 10000;
    $salary = $form['salary'];
    $salary = preg_replace('/[€]/i', '', $salary);
    if($salary < $value1 || $salary > $value2) {
        echo "bad values";
        return false;
    } else {
        echo "valid";
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex solution would look like this

```
^(?:10000|(?:(?:(?:2[5-9]\d)|[3-9]\d{2}|\d{4})(?:[,.]\d{2})?))€?$
```

See here online on [Regexr](http://regexr.com?2tti4)

But it would be better for checking if a value belongs to a range, not to use a regex. You can extract the value easily and do a normal <> check on numbers outside.

Answer (score 0):

My contribution. It works great.

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([0-9]+)|((([1-9][0-9]*)|([0-9]))([.,])[0-9]{1,2})$");
```