# PHP regex to find unencoded euro symbol

Tags: php, regex, euro

I'm in PHP. I'd like to find numbers in a sentence that start with a currency symbol, and returns the number. To search "I spent €100 on shoes" and return "100".

I've got this working for $ and £:

```
'/[$£]([0-9.]{1,})/'
```

But adding the € euro symbol doesn't work. (The sentences come from parsed emails, so I don't need to find €);

```
preg_match_all('/[€]([0-9.]{1,})/', $sentence, $match);
```

I've found the following on SO:
[regex for currency (euro)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221925/regex-for-currency-euro)
But it doesn't encode the euro symbol.

To encode the euro symbol, I've tried:

```
/[\x{20ac}]([0-9.]{1,})/u
"[^-a-zA-Z0-9.:,!+£$ \\ ". chr(164) ."]"
```

But can't figure it out. Any help?

Comment: I think you want the `u` modifier, to enable UTF-8 patterns. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: You may want to also look for entities representing euro symbol - `&euro;` and `&#8364;`

Comment: @tjm adding /u breaks the regex I have: "Compilation failed: invalid UTF-8 string at offset 2"

@dev-null-dweller Edited. I only have € because the text comes from emails and user input. I'm not changing € to &euro;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I put this in:

```
 echo preg_match("#€[0-9]{1,}#", "€1" )?1:0;
```

I get `1`, so you might not need unicode. But if you would like to use UTF-8 nevertheless, I found this as a comment under the PHP docs.

```
function unichr($u) {
    return mb_convert_encoding('&#' . intval($u) . ';', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
}
```

To get the €, you call `unichr(8364)`. Use that in place of the euro sign above and you'll be good. (I feel I should note: that I tested both as the unicode version:

```
preg_match("#".unichr(8364)."\s*([0-9]{1,})#u", unichr(8364). "1" )?1:0;
```

You might want to do `str_replace('€', unichr(8364), $str);` first...

PS. You probably also want to allow for spaces and decimals: `#€\s*([0-9]{1,}(\.?[0-9]{2}))#`

Comment: This worked once I got everything into UTF-8. Turned out the problems were further upstream. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

How about you replace the euro symbol with something else? E.g:

```
$str = 'I spent €100 on shoes.';
$tempStr = str_replace('€', '$', $str);
//$tempStr now contains: I spent $100 on shoes.

preg_match_all('/[€]([0-9.]{1,})/', $tempStr, $match);
```

Comment: You replace all `€` with `$` - do you really think `[€]([0-9.]{1,})` can find any match after it?